# Is there an online JSON to XML converter?

Tags: xml, json

I wonder if there is an online JSON to XML converter I can use.

Comment: http://programmerscalculator.apphb.com/Home/JsonToXml

Comment: My own one https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/json2xml/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure there is: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/

(URL fixed to moved location. This comment necessary to meet minimum edit requirements.)

Comment: It can't convert this to xml: {"docs": {"success": true}}

Comment: Seems like it only accepts strings as values. This one is converted successfully {"docs": {"success": "true"}}

Answer (score 1):

Another one
http://json.online-toolz.com/tools/xml-json-convertor.php

But it skips some data:

```
<test>
  <el id="1">content</el>
</test>
```

you'll get

```
{"test":{"el":"content"}}
```

So id attribute will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these:
http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was learning EmberJS so I have built another one XML to JSON online tool. It have an option to include attributes or not.

Check it out http://dfsq.info/xml2json.